# iOS - How To Fix This Animation In Table View Cell To Go Left and Then Back Again

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation, uikit

The goal is to have the first table view cell content move left for a time and then back again.

The bigger goal is that we will bounce the cell's content view slightly to the left and bounce in a red box then return the cell to normal. 
Although similar to another SO question, the answer does not reveal how to do this. Plus, this question would apply to anyone who wants to animate moving the cell content to the left temporarily and then back again. Thus, that's why it's a separate question.

The environment is iOS 11+ and iPhone app.

I have a new Table View project created that is animating the contentView moving via transform. However, it doesn't seem to remotely start in the normal position and then move as desired. The content starts off centered and then moves into place instead.

How can I get the contentView to animate moving a little to the left and then back again into its normal position?

**Project:** https://github.com/mikefinney/peekabooswipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote your code a little. You were applying a *transform* to the content view and the documentation suggests instead animating the `center` property when shifting the location.

```
func applyCellAnimations() {

        let originalCenter = contentView.center
        let offsetCenter = originalCenter.applying(.init(translationX: -44, y: 0))

        animateToCenter(offsetCenter) {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
                self.animateToCenter(originalCenter)
            })
        }
    }

    private func animateToCenter(_ center: CGPoint, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void = { }) {

        layoutIfNeeded()

        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: 1,
            delay: 0,
            options: [.curveEaseInOut],
            animations: {
                self.contentView.center = center
        }, completion: { didComplete in
            if didComplete { completionHandler() }
        })
    }
```

Comment: A good change and thank you for your reply. `self.contentView.transform = .identity` still has this behavior where it swipes in from the left. I need it to start normal and then nudge a little left.. and then ultimately go back to normal: https://youtu.be/R_cSstICOko

Comment: I see you edited it. I will check this out. Thanks, Hobbes the Tige :)

Comment: You did great @hobbes-the-tige  Thanks!  I put your solution in the master branch and noted that it came from you. :)